# Creating custom paths in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to create custom URLs for my menu items, such as mysite.com/aboutus rather than /node/2 or however it has it by default. In the menu configuration I changed the paths to what I want them to be, but I don't know how to change the paths of the pages to a custom name, rather than what Drupal defaults it as.

Answer (score 4):

Turn on the Path module, and download Pathauto. You can then create aliasing rules per content type, users, and taxonomy, and you can forget having to do this ever again.